# Equal functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $U$ is a connected open set on $R^n$ and $f,g:U \to \Bbb R$ are  functions and there is $a\in U$ such that $f(a)=g(a)$, $df(a)=dg(a)$
and $d^2f(x)=d^2g(x)$ for all $x\in U$, then  $f=g$.

Comment: Hi, I edited your question. Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: I did try define $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ in this new function $a$ is a critical point, i think construct an  open and closedset $A \subset U$. if $h \neq 0$